# Chrome.i18n doesnt work with Gmail change language

Tags: google-chrome-extension, internationalization, gmail

I am working on a gmail extension and that extension has implemented Chrome.i18n.
Issue i am facing is that Chrome.i18n only works when i change the browser language.
How can i detect the gmail lanugage change without changing browser language?

For example if browser language is Spanish following line

```
chrome.i18n.getMessage('sample_string')
```

will return Spanish text.

But if browser language is English and gmail language is Spanish then above line of code will return English language.

Can you please help me here how I can make Chrome.i18n work with gmail language change and if its not possible what are the alternatives.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n

Comment: `chrome.i18n` API can't do that so you'll have to use a custom js library.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you share a good library please ?

Comment: No, I haven't used any.